# Submit JS array to Eloquent controller

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

I'm finding it quite difficult to find documentation on how to build Eloquent functions to store data into a MySQL database.

At the moment I  can bring a variable into a MySQL database by taking the value from a form field:

```
$new_character->character_name = request('characterName');
```

characterName is the ID of a form field.

But I have variables that I want to bring into a new DB row. How do I do this?

I've tried using jquery to assign the array to a form:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="skillsField">
skillsVar = skillsList.toString(); // skillsVar is an array of strings
$('#skillsField').val(skillsVar);
```

And then in the Eloquent model:

```
$new_character->Trained_Skills = request('skillsField');
```

But this just results in *null* being submitted to the DB.

Help with the question is appreciated, pointing me to a document that simply explains DB CRUD in Laravel even more so!

Model & Controller:
https://pastebin.com/qVVxG3aF

View:
https://pastebin.com/Ef7b1uPp

View is very long, relevant lines of code are:
502 - 503: The forms I'm trying to use to hold the variables
559  - 581: THe JS code that runs when a button is clicked, that puts all ticked checkbox values into an array, turns it into a string and assigns it to a variable.

Comment: How are you populating "skillsList" - is this being populated on the clientside via user input and/or being set in the Javascript? From the outset it looks like skillsList and subsequently skillsVar is possibly empty so passing this to the controller could be your problem.

Further, assuming $new_character is a reference to an actual Character model that has been created your process should work, and that Trained_Skills is an actual column in the db and model.

A good and simple starting point that should help you: https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers

Comment: @MatthewFritz It's populated clientside: The user clicks checkboxes and a JS function loops through all the checkboxes and takes the values of the checked ones and puts them into an array. I'm using console.log() to see skillsList before I submit the form and it's working correctly. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Can you share your model, view and controller code? Will help to provide you with a proper answer.

Comment: @MatthewFritz Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code it appears that your model itself looks incomplete and lacking table structure and definition.

I've made some assumptions below based on your view and controller to determine what the model should appear to look like.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Character extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'characters'

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'player_id',
        'campaign_id',
        'character_name',
        'Race',
        'Class',
        'Level',
        'Strength',
        'Dexterity',
        'Constitution',
        'Intelligence',
        'Wisdom',
        'Charisma',
        'Proficiency',
        'Trained_Skills',
        'Languages',
        'Hit_Die',
        'HP'
    ];

    // If you have a specific id field as a primary key use this:
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public static function userChars()
    {
        return static::where('player_id', '=', \Auth::user()->id)->get();
    }

}
```

Then your controller looks fine in as far as it's creating the character and assigning values according to the incoming request object.

In your view, for the two fields you are using to insert the skills var value and the language var value, make sure you include the "name" as this is what is used for reference when passing the request object:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="skillsField" name="skillsField">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="languagesField" name="languagesField">
```

Finally, when testing on the controller side I recommend doing a **var_dump** on the request object, or at least on the **request('skillsField')** and **request('languagesField')** to make sure the request object actually contains the values you are expecting before trying to write to the DB table itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found out what the issue was: Those two fields I was using to insert the values were outside of the form div and so not being submitted via the submit button. I found that out while making those changes you suggested so thanks!

Comment: @RuairiMcNicholas - No prob. Glad you found the issue. It's little things like this which can be really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your input to this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="skillsField" id="skillsField">
```

Comment: No joy, still getting null. Thanks though!